# problem displaying random tweet pulled from feed on website

Tags: python, html, twitter, embed

I would like to take a random tweet from a user’s feed and embed it on my site. How do i scrub the data from a feed and process it
How would i go about this?
I have tried to use python to do it

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: I’ve tried scrubbing with python but running a scrub for every user that clicks seems like a very inefficient process ( maybe impossible)

Comment: Please create at least a reproducible code block on any online editor which people can see what is the problem

Comment: “Scrubbing with Python” I’m not understanding what this means. Can you post code?